# Position a button directly to the right of a label (Swift)

Tags: ios, image, swift, interface-builder

I am trying to place a square button to the right of a label in Swift using interface builder. I position them then apply constraints but I can never see the label. I am trying to position it like in the image below:
http://postimg.org/image/yybaq37kv/

How can I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to setup your constraints like shown in this image

- Align bottom your button and label
- Align Top your button and label
- Leading space of button to to be zero / or trailing space of label to be zero

[image: constraints autolayout]